# Devise - Unable to Get Past Welcome Screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to integrate Devise into my application. I installed it and it is working properly. I have the sign up and adding to the DB working. I have the sign in working. My problem is no matter what I do, I can not seem to get the sign in or sign up page to go anywhere other than the Rails Default Welcome Screen.

I know their are numerous posts about similar issues. But I am stumped because all the solutions outlined do not appear to have any effect.  Even after starting and stopping the server (when changing the routes)  Each time goes back to the welcome page.  If anyone would be kind enough to show me a sample of a known working route.rb I'd appreciate it.

Currently this is in mine:

devise_for :users 
root :to => "home#index"

Comment: What do you mean by " go anywhere other than the Rails Default Welcome Screen" . As far as i understood your question this should help you this is my routes.rb file's devise config   ---   devise_for :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }

Comment: Do you have any other models in your app?
Share you routes file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is delete `public/index.html`.

Comment: Thank you for all three answers.  As a newbie I was spinning my wheels.  In my zest to move foward I was taking two steps back.  Gabe you are correct that removing that file helped me understand what was going on.  Abhay your comments have helpedme better understand working with the routes and redirecting the page.